# discord.py - Getting all available roles of a guild

Tags: python, python-3.7, discord.py

I notice there is a method for the `Guild` object for fetching all roles of a guild. My problem is that I cannot install `discord.py==1.3.0` using pip. 
[image: Method for Guild object only available for 1.3.0]
Is there another way to get all the guild's roles in `discord.py==1.2.3`?

Comment: Use [`guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Returns a list of the guild’s roles in hierarchy order.

The first element of this list will be the lowest role in the hierarchy.
```

Once you have  list of roles you can iterate through it and get its name, id etc.

[Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild.roles)

Comment: I didn't do it right before. My blind self didn't see it. For future readers add the guild.roles method

Answer (score 0):

Download it here: https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/#files and follow the instructions to import

Comment: It is not yet available for download through PIP yet. Maybe final release is not out.