# Get the list of name of all existing roles of Discord server - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord

def read_token():
    with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0].strip()

token = read_token()

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    guild = client.get_guild(id)
    channels = ['general']

user = guild.roles

if str(message.channel) in channels:
        if message.content == "!role":
            await message.channel.send(user)

client.run(token)
```

This gives the output

```
[<Role id=[confidential] name='@everyone'>, <Role id=707478326872375317 name='test role'>, <Role id=705472652411666482 name='dear'>, <Role id=705472646896418846 name='issue'>, <Role id=705456460024250409 name='pro'>, <Role id=705456411127316540 name='ansh'>, <Role id=705012241426284545 name='gsheet-bot'>]
```

I instead want to get just the names and not the IDs in the list. What can I do?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56919488/1935238) answer your question?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere not really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `user = guild.roles` returns a list where each element is a discord.Role object you can then access the name attribute of the discord.Role object.

Try the following to get a list of role names (not sure why you are naming the variable user when it is for roles):

```py
user = [r.name for r in guild.roles]
```